# error C2065: 'static_pointer_cast' : undeclared identifier - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

I am trying to static cast a `std::shared_ptr` to its base class. Given the classes:

```
class ImportFileSetting {};
class ImportFileSettingSelect:ImportFileSetting {}
```

I tried the following code:

```
std::shared_ptr<ImportFileSettingSelect> selectedSheet_ = std::make_shared<ImportFileSettingSelect>();
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ImportFileSetting>> settings_;
settings_.push_back(static_pointer_cast<ImportFileSetting>(selectedSheet_));
```

which I found according to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast). But it fails to compile with:

```
5>src\TechAdminServices\database\techCore\processes\ImportDataSourceExcel.cpp(32): error C2065: 'static_pointer_cast' : undeclared identifier
5>src\TechAdminServices\database\techCore\processes\ImportDataSourceExcel.cpp(32): error C2275: 'ImportFileSetting' : illegal use of this type as an expression
5>          d:\techsys\techadmin\techadminservices\src\techadminservices\database\techcore\processes\ImportFileSetting.h(7) : see declaration of 'ImportFileSetting'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the namespace:

```
settings_.push_back(std::static_pointer_cast<ImportFileSetting>(selectedSheet_));
//                  ^^^^^
```

Comment: But why is a qualified name required here? I'd expect the unqualified name to work and find the correct overload using ADL (as both `static_pointer_cast` and `shared_ptr` are in namespace `std`). But clearly, it fails.

Comment: @MarcMutz-mmutz [P0846](https://wg21.link/p0846) was the paper that allowed ADL to work in this case, that paper was written a year and a half after I wrote this answer.